Bash debugging - display line numbers
I am attempting to get line numbers displayed on the console while debugging a sourced Bash script.
I use the following code to enable debugging:
set -x
export PS4="Line $LINENO"

but I am getting the following output:
set -x
export 'PS4=Line 26'
PS4='Line 26'
LLine 26sourced=0
LLine 26'[' -n '' ']'
LLine 26'[' -n '' ']'
LLine 26'[' -n '5.1.16(1)-release' ']'
LLine 26return 0
LLine 26sourced=1
LLine 26'[' '!' -n 1 ']'
LLine 26'[' -n UM ']'
LLLine 26currentVe
LLLine 26'[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
LLLine 26/usr/lib/command-not-found -- currentVe
currentVe: command not found
LLLine 26return 127
LLine 26'[' -n ']'
LLine 26'[' '' '!=' UM ']'
LLine 26echo 'Trying to use Virtual environment UM while  is still active'
Trying to use Virtual environment UM while  is still active
LLine 26return 2

The number 26 is the line number of the Bash statement where PS4 is set.
This technique used to work but I now can find no way of making it useful. I have tried firing up a new Bash shell and even rebooting my computer without any sucess. Any ideas on what I should do? I am trying to debug a problem where the line numbers could be invaluable.

The problem is that you used double-quotes in export PS4="Line $LINENO", which means that $LINENO is expanded immediately and its value ("26") used to set the PS4 variable. Use single-quotes instead of double- to prevent this premature evaluation. See "What are the differences between single and double quotes in Bash?"

Thanks for your help. That fixed it. My problem is that Shell scripting is very much a secondary tool for me and I am not as knowegable as I should be. I generally use Python but have a situation where I must interface dirctly with a shell script which controls an important part of the Python enviorment. This script supports Bourne based shells and offers alternative scripts for csh, fish and zsh. That is how they deal with cross-shell necessities.The scripts are sourced rather than being run normally because they are expected to modify the parent environment.
